# PropertyInfo.SetValue() doesn't work when the property in a base class doesn't have a setter

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am using reflection to get objects. Initially I created a class with an "Id" property without a setter because I don't want the user of the framework to set a value to the Id property:

```
public class Client {
    public int? Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Client(string name, string email) {
        Id = null;
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
    }
}
```

Using reflection I am able to set a value to the Id property using the following code:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    if (prop.Name == "Id") {
       prop.SetValue(obj, id);
       break;
    }
}
```

But when I use inheritance the PropertyInfo.SetValue doesn't work for the Id property:

```
public abstract class Client {
    public int? Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public Client(string name, string email) {
        Id = null;
        Name = name;
        Email = email;
    }
}

public class PhysicalPerson : Client {
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

        public PhysicalPerson(string name, string email, string cpf, DateTime birthDate) : base(name, email) { 
            CPF = cpf;
            BirthDate = birthDate;
        }
    }
```

When prop.SetValue() is executed, it returns the exception "Property set method not found".
I know the Id property doesn't have a setter, but why it works when there is no inheritance?
I really want to keep the Id property without a setter. Does anyone know how to circumvent this situation?

Comment: Try changing the setter to internal, private setter can only be used in constructor.

Comment: `var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.GetProperty; var person = new PhysicalPerson(...); person.GetType().BaseType.GetProperty("Id", flags).SetValue(person, 100);`

Comment: Thanks Jimi. I used "protected" and it worked.Hadi explained in his answer what happened. "Protected" propagates the setter to the inheritted classes (private doesn't).

Comment: That code works with `private set`, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a `private` modifier is applied to the `Id`'s setter method, the property **has** a `SetMethod()` but it's accessible only in the `Client` class. So you can set a value using reflection. But if you remove the `set;`, it makes a similar error in the code without inheritance. Try this:

```
public int? Id { get; }
```

In contrast, when you inherit a new class from the base class, the `Id`'s setter is not inherited and `SetMethod()` will be null. Now, you are going to set a value using the child that has not inherited the `set;` and indeed the `PhysicalPerson`'s `Id` property's `SetMethod()` is null.

Comment: Thank you Hadi. I changed the modifier from private to protected and now it is working fine.

Comment: I tried this and when trying to call it on inherited class it failed. I had to add a protected setter. 
Although I am using .Net 6